# why aren't my discord bot commands working

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

im new to code and i'm just trying to make a discord bot but i made commands and i made it possible for my bot's status to say something but none of it works. it goes online and it doesn't tell me anything's wrong with my code but none of it works.

code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client();

let prefix=".";

bot.on("ready", () => {
  bot.user.setStatus("idle")
console.log("lets gooo")
});

const update = () => {
    bot.user.setActivity(".help | residing on " + bot.guilds.size + " Servers", { type: 'WATCHING' }); 
};

bot.on('ready', update);
bot.on('guildCreate', update);
bot.on('guildRemove', update);
bot.on("message", message => {
    
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.channel.type === "dm") return;

    let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
    let command = messageArray[0];
    let args = messageArray.slice(1);

   if(!command.startsWith(prefix)) return;

});

    if(command === `${prefix}userinfo`) {
        let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor(message.author.username)
        .setColor("#5ED315")
        .setThumbnail( `${message.author.avatarURL}`)
        .addField("Name", `${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`)
        .addField("ID", message.author.id)
       
        message.reply("check dms");
        message.channel.send({embed}); 

    }; 


    if("command" === `${prefix}help`) {
        let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .addField(".help", "gives you this current information")
        .setTitle("help")
        .setColor("#5ED315")
        .addField(".user", "gives you info about a user(currently being worked on)")
        .addField(".server","gives you info about a server(currently working on it)") 
        .addField("link to support server","https://discord.gg/cRJk74kDvj")
        .addField("invite link for bot","https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=771489748651868173&permissions=8&scope=bot")
    };

  message.reply("here's a list of commands that i'm able to do")
        message.channel.send({embed});
    

 
    messageArray = message.content.split("");
    let command = messageArray[0];
        if(command === `${prefix}serverinfo`) {
            let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setAuthor(message.author.username)
            .setColor("#5ED315")
            .addField("Name", `${message.guild.name}`)
            .addField("Owner", `${message.guild.owner.user}`)
            .addField("Server ID" , message.guild.id)
            .addField("User Count", `${message.guild.members.filter(m => m.presence.status !== 'offline').size} / ${message.guild.memberCount}`)
            .addField("Roles", `${message.guild.roles.size}`);


            message.channel.send({embed});
         };

bot.login("bot token");
```

why isn't anything working?? i really need help

Comment: Seeing as you are closing your `message` listener way too soon, you should have an error like `command is not defined` even before your bot connects.

Answer (score 0):

```
26:
27:     if(!message.startsWith(prefix)) return;
28: 
29: });
    ^^^
```

There's your problem. You're closing the message handler too early, so it doesn't bother to touch the command code. (Well, it does, but not the way you want it to.)

You should move that closing `});` to after your command definitons. (before the `bot.login`)

Comment: do i have to get rid of every closing and add it above bot.login?

Comment: @greened, sorry for the late response. Remove the closing braces highlighted on line 29 and move them to the line before the bot.login.